# How to create PostgreSQL DB project in Visual Studio 2019 as like SQL Database project

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2019

**How to create** a **PostgreSQL database project in Visual Studio 2019 as like we are doing SQL DB Project????**.

Visual Studio has provided SQL Database project template but I didn't find anything for PostgreSQL Database.
We are using **AzureDevops + GITHUB for repositories**. So need to create one repo for PostgreSQL schemas
Also need to c**reate postgreSQL database through CI/CD (Jenkin tool/AzureDevOps tool)**

Need to maintain version control of each database object in the form of SQL script file. So, is there any such provision (may be in the form of plug-in) in Visual Studio 2019 or can we utilize SQL server database project for storing PostgreSQL schemas?

Comment: Did you ever find a reasonable solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Entity Framework for PostgreSQL.
Just follow the directions from these links.
https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-postgresql-c6fa09681624